# How do you loop through a lot of dictionary references efficiently?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having a problem that probably has an easy solution, but I've tried everything I know.

I'm trying to write a program to automatically calculate the most efficient way to build a factory in Satisfactory, and while trying to reference the dict of items and their recipes, I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Codes\Python Testing\satisfactory.py", line 56, in <module>
    main(item)
  File "C:\Users\name\Desktop\Codes\Python Testing\satisfactory.py", line 54, in main
    mainrq1a = itemList[item]['rqAmounts'][i]
KeyError: 0
```

For context, I'm trying to set the main required amount from item 1 to the value of this dictionary here:

```
"steelingot": {
    "name": "Steel Ingot",
    "minAmount": 1,

    "rq": {
        "rq1": "ironore",
        "rq2": "coalore"
    },

    "rqAmounts": {
        "rq1a": 1,
        "rq2a": 1
    },

    "builtBy": "foundry"
}
```

And this is the code I'm using:

```
for i in range(len(rqAll) - 2):
     try: itemList[rqAll[i]]['isBasic']
     except:
         print("more to come")
     else:
         mainrq1a = itemList[item]['rqAmounts'][i]
         print(mainrq1a)
```

This will run through every item in the required list, (rqAll) and check to see if it's a basic item. If it is, it *should* take the required amount to craft for that item, but that's where my problem is.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The key problem is that ['rqAmounts'] is a dictionary, not a list.  You can't index it by integer (0).  The data is organized strangely. if this is trying to say that 'Steel Ingot' requires 1 unit of coalore and 1 unit of ironore, then those should be stored together, like `{... 'requires': [ [ 1, "coalore" ], [ 1, "ironore" ] ] ... }`.  As it is, there's no way to link "rq1" with "rq1a".

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! I noticed this literally 5 minutes before I went to check on here lol. But your fix on the problem is very helpful, thanks again!